# Generate Sub-Comments with WP-CLI

Tags: comments, wp-cli

Using wp-cli, it is possible to generate random comments for posts.  Is it also possible to generate sub-comments?  If so; how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not available in WP CLI. See https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/master/php/commands/comment.php#L136

If you want, you can have your own customized comment generation command. See command cookbook. http://wp-cli.org/docs/commands-cookbook/

Comment: Thanks.  If I come up with something worthwhile, I publish it somewhere.